# Attempted to load class "Join" from namespace "DS\ApiBundle\Command\Expr"

Tags: symfony, left-join

I am trying to join two tables in symfony. It's giving me following error:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException]
>   Attempted to load class "Join" from namespace
>   "DS\ApiBundle\Command\Expr".    Did you forget a "use" statement for
>   e.g. "Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Join" or "Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join"?

My code is down below:

```
 $student = $this->schoolManager->createQueryBuilder('s')                      
    ->leftJoin('s.schoolId', 'm', Expr\Join::ON ,'s.schoolId = m.school')        
    ->getQuery();
```

Every school has member.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the forum.

You can fix this error by a) just using the string presentation of the join expression:

```
$student = $this->schoolManager->createQueryBuilder('s')                      
    ->leftJoin('s.schoolId', 'm', 'ON' ,'s.schoolId = m.school')        
    ->getQuery();
```

of by b) including the use statement for the relevant doctrine class (in the beginning of your class)

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr;

...

$student = $this->schoolManager->createQueryBuilder('s')                      
    ->leftJoin('s.schoolId', 'm', Expr\Join::ON ,'s.schoolId = m.school')        
    ->getQuery();
```

Comment: its giving me error as-->Error: Class DS\AppBundle\Entity\School has no association named schoolId

Comment: That would be then another issue - which would normally be better of as it's own question.. But as the error says, your query is trying to use member variable "schoolId" from your entity - but doesn't find it (= that isn't defined in your entity). I could take a guess that it should be just "id" (instead of "schoolId") what you are accessing from the School entity - but unless/until you include the School entity code in your question, guessing/assuming is the only thing I can do for this error.